# Installing Influx db on windows

Tags: windows, influxdb, failed-installation

I have tried to install influx db on windows 10 using following steps from a blog. 
However after "**go get -u -f ./...**" command I get following error message.

```
C:\>cd Go
C:\Go>mkdir projects
C:\Go>set "GOPATH=C:\Go\projects"
C:\Go>cd %gopath%
C:\Go\projects>go get github.com/influxdata/influxdb
C:\Go\projects>cd src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb
C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb>go get -u -f ./...
package github.com/uber-go/zap: code in directory C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\uber-go\zap expects import "go.uber.org/zap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a current issue with the Zap library:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/8029#issuecomment-281432839

You can download a pre-compiled Windows binary from the Influxdata website:
https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads